# Error in creating AmazonS3 Bean after installing AWS CLI in Spring Application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I try to use AmazonS3 in my application using Spring Boot, Java, AWS SDK S3
I get credentials from application.properties and all work fine
Here my configuration file for creating AmazonS3 Bean

```
@Configuration
public class StorageConfiguration {

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String accessSecret;
    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 s3Client() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region).build();
    }

}
```

Then I install AWS CLI on my computer and always get next exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3Client' defined in class path resource [com/cinemalab/aws/service/fileService/configurations/StorageConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3]: Factory method 's3Client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3]: Factory method 's3Client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:53) ~[httpcore-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:57) ~[httpcore-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:47) ~[httpcore-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:96) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:105) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:63) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:620) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:181) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:165) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:74) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:59) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:347) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:331) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:239) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:225) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:724) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:28) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.504.jar:na]
    at com.cinemalab.aws.service.fileService.configurations.StorageConfiguration.s3Client(StorageConfiguration.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cinemalab.aws.service.fileService.configurations.StorageConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e0fa3205.CGLIB$s3Client$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cinemalab.aws.service.fileService.configurations.StorageConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e0fa3205$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8149035.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.cinemalab.aws.service.fileService.configurations.StorageConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e0fa3205.s3Client(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 48 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.504</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I tried to configure AWS CLI via aws configure
I tried to delete AWS CLI
I tried different credential for creating Bean

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the error `"java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE"` is raised when there are some problems with the dependencies.

Can you check that you don't have duplicated dependencies?

Hence, I suggest you to not focus too much now on the bean configuration but start google for `"java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE"`.

Comment: Added the list of dependencies. I use Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT. 
Why do I connect this error with installing AWS CLI?
Because if I use another Laptop - it works
Checked "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE", but I can't see version mismatched or dependency duplicating in the project

Answer (score 0):

`com.googlecode.jsontoken` has `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15`
And  `aws-java-sdk-s3` has `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).